# How to download file to Download's directory with Ionic Framework?

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, download

I'm trying with `ngCordova` but the `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` property is `null`.

I have also tried combining the use of `ngCordova` with `requestFileSystem`, but still, the file is not saved in the "Download's".

Example of my code:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(directory) {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.download(
        encodeURI("http://example.com/sample.pdf"),
        directory.root.nativeURL + 'sample.pdf',
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        },
        false
    );
}, function(err){console.error(err)});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Download/' + 'sample.pdf'` instead of `directory.root.nativeURL + 'sample.pdf'`

Comment: This Question is about download file to "Downloads folder" of Android, not about "cordova.file.documentsDirectory null".
Definitely, you answer is too poor and not is constructive.

Comment: You said "I'm trying with ngCordova but the cordova.file.documentsDirectory property is null"

Comment: Yes, and I says "also tray with "also tried combining the use of `ngCordova` with `requestFileSystem`". This question not is about `documentsDirectory`, is about How I can download file and store it on "Downloads Folder" on Android.

Comment: This look much better. I'll try it. Thanks! +1

Comment: @OlafErlandsen No problem. Check https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

Comment: This answer works perfectly. I clarify that it is necessary to add write permissions for the application, otherwise it will not be able to download. Thanks @WadeTyler

Comment: @OlafErlandsen No problem. Glad to help.

Comment: @OlafErlandsen Can you tell me what permission I need for Download directory? I am getting `/storage/emulated/0/Download/montages.json: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`. I have tried READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and MANAGE_DOCUMENTS permissions. Did not helped :/

Comment: Well, whats Android version are using you?

Comment: @Luckylooke Have you found a solution for this ? I am facing the same issu e

Comment: @noor yes I have succeeded with combination of manifest permissions and cordova-plugin-android-permissions for runtime permissions needed for android 5+

Answer (score 2):

I solved it via the following code:

```
const ROOT_DIRECTORY = 'file:///sdcard//';
const downloadFolderName = 'Download';


this.file.createDir(ROOT_DIRECTORY, downloadFolderName, true)
  .then((entries) => {
 //then your code
 fileTransfer.download(fileLocation,this.ROOT_DIRECTORY+this.downloadFolderName+'/'+ 'sample.pdf').then((entry) => {
}
//ends of your code ^^
})
  .catch((error) => {
    alert('error' + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```