# Ionic 3 - download a file to directory

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the similar problem like here: 
[How to download file to Download's directory with Ionic Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491042/how-to-download-file-to-downloads-directory-with-ionic-framework)

I got success alert after download but I can't see the file in an Android file explorer under the path displayed after succeed download: file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.fileTest/image.jpg

My code:

```
download(){

const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
const url = "http://cdna.allaboutvision.com/i/conditions-2016/heterochromia-kate-bosworth-660x660-with-credit.jpg";

fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'laska.jpg', true).then((entry) => {

  const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: `Download Succeeded!`,
    subTitle: `was successfully downloaded to: ${entry.toURL()}`,
    buttons: ['Ok']
  });
  alertSuccess.present();

}, (error) => {

  const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: `Download Failed!`,
    subTitle: `was not successfully downloaded. Error code: ${error.code}`,
    buttons: ['Ok']
  });
  alertFailure.present();
});
}
```

Could I somehow manage to save this file in e.g "Download" folder or "Documents"? I also tried changing destination path to:

```
cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Download/'
```

In that case, I received error 1.

In many examples I see people use 
       window.requestFileSystem() 
but it looks like the window doesn't have this method for me. I use visual studio code and ionic 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code that downloads a file to Downloads directory:

```
downloadFile() {
  this.fileTransfer.download("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/23/21/soap-bubble-1959327_960_720.jpg", this.file.externalRootDirectory + 
  '/Download/' + "soap-bubble-1959327_960_720.jpg").then()
}

getPermission() {
  this.androidPermissions.hasPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    .then(status => {
      if (status.hasPermission) {
        this.downloadFile();
      } 
      else {
        this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
          .then(status => {
            if(status.hasPermission) {
              this.downloadFile();
            }
          });
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You got little bit mistake in `fileTransfer.download`**

instead of `this.file.applicationStorageDirectory` use `this.file.dataDirectory`

Comment: I also tried that. The problem is if I use dataDirectory I got info that dowload succeed but file is not available in android file explorer. When I use applicationStorageDirectory i receive error 1

Comment: @bambaniasz Had you find any solution , can we store file in Downloads folder in ionic ?

Comment: @NarendraSinghRathore You need to ask for permission first.

Comment: @bambaniasz Had already requested on load, but still not able to store it.